# I have a folder containing of all .json files. I want to edit all of these json by adding a new key and values like "value":{"Key": ["val1", "val2"]

Tags: python, json

PYTHON:

I have a folder containing of all .json files. I want to edit all of these json by adding a new key and values like

```
"value":{"Key": ["val1", "val2"],"original_key1": "true", "original_key2": "1654016551303"
```

I also have a csv file containing two columns. First column is the name of the json file and the second column is the list of val, val2, val3 etc which I want to add to the json as mentioned in the subject.

Could you please help me out?

I also have a csv file containing two columns. First column is the name of the json file and the second column is the list of val, val2, val3 etc which I want to add to the json as mentioned in the subject.

Comment: I guess you will have to start writing code. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Use `json.load()` to load the JSON file into a dictionary. Add the keys to the dictionary. Then use `json.dump()` to write the dictionary back to the JSON file.